# HashTable.containKey Time Complexity.....!

Tags: hashtable

What time it will take to find the key inside the HashTable by using HashTable.containKey(ValueObject), I know lookup value will take  O(1) time.

```
    Hashtable.ContainsKey
```

If key lookup will  take O(1) time then why dont we have a method from which we can get the key by giving value object ?

To find a key we need to use Entry class object and iterator it to find key.

Comment: Because there is a reason that the "key" is actually called the "key"? One key matches one value. One value can have several keys.

Comment: What language is this?